# Looping and assigning values through SASS

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

Before judging my situation, I am not using a typical Bootstrap approach to assign custom colors to variables.  I am in a unique situation of depending on the Bootstrap CDN, and re-creating custom SASS variables that *look like* BS4 variables. Read on!

I feel like I am so close on the the following process.  All I want to do is assign my array values to a class property name like so, (i.e. background-color: $theme-primary!important;)

```
//ORIGINAL THEME VARIABLES
$theme-colors: (primary:$m-color-blue, secondary: $m-color-off-white, success: $m-color-grey, info: $m-color-grey-light, warning: $m-color-gold, light: $m-color-white, dark: $m-color-grey-dark);
$theme-primary: map-get($theme-colors, "primary");
$theme-secondary: map-get($theme-colors, "secondary");
$theme-success: map-get($theme-colors, "success");
$theme-info: map-get($theme-colors, "info");
$theme-warning: map-get($theme-colors, "warning");
$theme-light: map-get($theme-colors, "light");
$theme-dark: map-get($theme-colors, "dark");


//MY LOOP TO ASSIGN BS4 BG COLORS TO MY CUSTOM COLORS. 
$classes: primary secondary success warning danger light;

@each $class in $classes {
    html body .bg-#{$class} {
      //MY ISSUE IS HERE...IT DOES NOT LIKE HOW I AM FORMING THIS PROPERTY.  SYNTAX ISSUE???
      background-color: $theme-#{class} !important;
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to compile it, I get the following error:

`messageOriginal: Undefined variable: "$theme-".`

I think I get the error, but how do I resolve?

Comment: import the theme variable file in this current file

Comment: I have a feeling its a syntax error issue...for some reason, it may be illegal to have `$theme-#{class}` - I'm thinking my format is wrong...I'm trying to append my #{class} variable to $theme-, which is a partial name of another variable.

Comment: @Sonia, the variables are now added

Comment: Are you using some framework/theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this would be necessary since there's already utility classes available for this; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color

You can also feed the bootstrap sass straight into your build pipeline to use all their vars, mixins, functions already;
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

However, I think you're looking for something more like this amigo; Cheers

```
$classes: (
  primary: "#f00",
  secondary: "#ddd",
  success: "#00f",
  warning: "#0f0",
  danger: "#f00",
  light: "#eee"
);

@each $key, $val in $classes {
  .bg-#{$key} {
    background-color: #{$val} !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was making life complicated with my situation.  Many many thanks in helping me solve my issue by reminding me of true key value pairs, in a sass loop, and just going with that.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're not importing the `$theme` variable from your `_base` / other directory then how do you expect the script to know what to fill it in with?
2. Your syntax is wrong, you need to wrap `$theme` with `#{}` as well so it's `#{$theme}-#{class}`

**working example:**

```
$classes: primary secondary success warning danger light;
$theme: 'blue'; // switch this with import theme.

@each $class in $classes {
    html body .bg-#{$class} {
      background-color: #{$theme}-#{$class} !important;
    }
}
```

**generated css:**

```
html body .bg-primary {
  background-color: blue-primary !important;
}

html body .bg-secondary {
  background-color: blue-secondary !important;
}

html body .bg-success {
  background-color: blue-success !important;
}

html body .bg-warning {
  background-color: blue-warning !important;
}

html body .bg-danger {
  background-color: blue-danger !important;
}

html body .bg-light {
  background-color: blue-light !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap4, you can directly add a new color to $theme-colors, add the new key and value

```
$theme-colors: (
  "custom-color": #900
);
```